# Connection with specified ID NOT FOUND ASP.NET MVC / C# / IIS

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I deployed my application to IIS, and I get this error:

[image: Error Image Click Here]

Comment: An unhandled exception like that can only be analyzed and resolved by its developers.

Comment: could you please event viewer application log? what kind of database provider you are using? could you please share the code by using you are trying to connect the database?

Comment: I'm using the Entity Framework and SQL server